# Intellij IDEA autocomplete java core library

Tags: intellij-idea

I seem to have added the core library to some kind of Autocomplete-Blacklist. If I do `new File`, it offers only `com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Package.File` as autocomplete. This is the same for different Projects, so it seems to be a global option.

I already tried to recreate the SDK under Platform-Setting, without success.

I would appreciate any idea how to fix that.

Robin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File->Settings->Editor->Auto Import->Exclude from Import and Completion

Comment: jupp, there it was. Thank you!